# Exception - Combining two data sets in HiveQL

Tags: sql, exception, hiveql

I am facing Analytics Exception while having inner data sets to be combined.

**Query**:

```
Select key,days
    FROM
    (
        Select key          
        FROM sls where id =14004
    ) AS first
    JOIN 
    (
        Select seckey ,days
        FROM
        (
            Select seckey , MAX(opp_days) As days from sls_daily Where id=14004 Group By key
        ) As f
        JOIN
        (
            Select  key,est,cls,days from sls_daily Where dw_cid=14004
        ) As s
        ON f.days = s.days  AND  f.key= s.key
    ) AS second
    ON second.seckey = first.key
```

**Exception**:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 15: ) AS first ^ Encountered:
>   FIRST Expected: IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

What is the reason for the error.

Comment: `second` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, needs to be delimited as  `"second"`.

Comment: `first` and `second` are reserved words in Hiveql (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords).  Choose different table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid `reserved` words in `SQL`.

Try like this

```
Select `key`,`days`
    FROM
    (
        Select `key`         
        FROM sls where id =14004
    ) AS `first`
    JOIN 
    (
        Select seckey ,`days`
        FROM
        (
            Select seckey , MAX(opp_days) As `days` from sls_daily Where id=14004 Group By key
        ) As f
        JOIN
        (
            Select  `key`,est,cls,`days` from sls_daily Where dw_cid=14004
        ) As s
        ON f.`days` = s.`days`  AND  f.`key`= s.`key`
    ) AS `second`
    ON `second`.seckey = `first`.`key`
```

Comment: What is the reserved word in the query? I am unable figure out it. And your answer is working fine now.

Comment: It is built in variable. You can't use it as user defined variable.